# Haskell Pattern matching in a Function

Tags: haskell

The two-argument function check returns True exactly when both
Boolean operands have the same value. Otherwise it returns False.
I should implement it using :

```
check :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
```

1)- Conditional expressions(checkA)

```
checkA x y = if x < y then False else True
```

-
2)-Guarded equations (checkB).

```
checkB x y | x < y = False  | otherwise =True
```

3)-Pattern matching (checkc).

,but here I get an error

```
checkC x y  False False = True
          True True = True
          False True = False
          True False = False
```

How can I use Pattern matching to say (if this and that are equivalent then ...)  when x and y are numbers(int)?

Comment: Here `x` and `y` seem to be `Bool`s, and your condition does not look correct.

Comment: As for `Int`s, one can write `Int` literals, but since that domain is huge, it would really be a (very) bad idea.

Comment: check :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool do you mean this ??

Comment: it's a homework and I have to do it today -_-

Comment: If `x` and `y` are booleans, you can simply enumerate all possible choices and you're done. With ints, you can't do this (because there are infinitely many of them), so pattern-matching is not an option.

Comment: can you give me an example ) @ForceBru

Comment: Do you understand how pattern matching works in general? The `Bool` type is a union with two cases `True` and `False` so you can match against those values directly e.g. `f True = ...`

Comment: @Amerov, literally enumerate all possible choices and define what the function returns in each case, like this: `check True True = True`, then, on the next line, `check False False = True`. I'll let you finish this yourself)

Comment: actually no that's why I asked for an example @Lee

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks <3

Comment: @ForceBru Parse error in pattern: checkc
   |
32 | checkc x y : False False = True
   | ^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
Prelude>  I got this error

Comment: Did you input `checkc | 32 | checkc x y : False False = True` as your code?

Comment: yes  and  it returns an error and there is  a red line under the name checkc  and x  y

Comment: @Amerov, but... what is it supposed to mean? Doesn't make much sense to me, and to the compiler too. Also, this is absolutely not what I was talking about. Please read about pattern-matching somewhere (you've got the power of Google at your fingertips!)

Comment: @ForceBru If i didn't understand something doesn't mean to be mean with me ! either help freindly or don't    anyway  thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pattern match against bools because there's a finite (and small) number of combinations. Consider the whole combination space of `Bool`s (which is defined as `n^n` where `n` is the size of the space)

```
False False
False True
True False
True True
```

It's trivial to enumerate these by hand in `check`

```
check :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
check False False = True
check False True  = False
check True False  = False
check True True   = True
```

But as you can deduce, `Int`s are not as trivial, since the space of all integers is literally infinite.

You can pattern match in this way with ints if you have an infinite amount of programming time and hard drive space, because you have an infinite amount of patterns to write.

```
check :: Int -> Int -> Bool
check 0 0 = True
check 1 1 = True
check (-1) (-1) = True
check 2 2 = True
check (-2) (-2) = True
-- etc literally until infinity
check _ _ = False
```

The way to write this is to either use guards:

```
check :: Int -> Int -> Bool
check x y | x == y    = True
          | otherwise = False
```

Or realize that there is a pretty standard function that already does this -- maybe you've heard of it? :-)

```
check :: Int -> Int -> Bool
check = (==)
```

Comment: but in your code the definition looks different (check :: Int -> Int -> Bool)and this a homework i can't change it  :,(  I'm given  the definition and I should continue with it

Comment: @Amerov What's it supposed to say? `check :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool` will only accept booleans (by definition) so the whole crux of your question (comparing integers to integers) is suspect :)

Comment: @Amerov Your last example (`checkC`) is failing for the same reason. You've defined a two-parameter function `checkC :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`, then provided a four-parameter function (`checkC x y boolA boolB`)